What does Sirach 21:21 mean by ' bracelet on the right arm '?
We read in Sirach 21:21(NRSVACE):

To the sensible person education is like a golden ornament, and like a bracelet on the right arm.

Most other Versions do not have the adjective  ' right' qualifying 'arm' .Perhaps, the usage came from a proverb around the life of soldiers who wore heavy bracelets on the arm, mostly on the right,  to hit the enemy with. Maybe, Verse 20 goes well with such a prospect:

To a person without any sense, an education is like handcuffs,

My question is : what does Sirach 21:21 mean by ' bracelet on the right arm ' ?

21 Ὡς κόσμος χρυσοῦς φρονίμῳ παιδεία, καὶ ὡς χλιδὼν ἐπὶ βραχίονι δεξιῷ.
First, the last word in the verse (δεξιῷ - dex-ee-os') means "right." It is also the word from which we get our English word "dexterous." Second, most of the translations I was able to consult do include the adjective "right," so it is safe to say that the text does mean "right arm" specifically. In ancient societies as well as sometimes today, the right side correlates to righteousness and public deeds such as taking food from the communal dish at table, (Mark 14:20) while the left signifies wrong choices and private tasks such as wiping oneself after defecating.
Contextually, we are dealing with a contrast between wisdom and foolery. I see two implications regarding the meaning of the particular verse. Wisdom is an ornament to the wise and it is also a means of protection against sin.

19 To the senseless, education is fetters on the feet,
like manacles on the right hand. 20 Fools raise their voice in laughter,
but the prudent at most smile quietly. 21 Like a gold ornament is education to the wise,
like a bracelet on the right arm.

Thus, the bracelet of wisdom contrasts directly to the manacles (handcuffs) of folly. Both are placed on the right arm/hand, representing one's public persona or reputation. To the fool, knowledge becomes a snare because he uses it with sinful intent, which ends in his downfall. But wisdom serves both as an ornament and also as a means of protection for the wise, as with the "bracelet" or armlet/bracer describer in 2 Samuel 1:10.

I took the crown that was upon his head
and the bracelet that was on his arm, and have brought them hither
unto my lord.” KJ21

Conclusion: the bracelet of Sirach 21:21 is a metaphor of wisdom, which serves both to ornament and protection the reputation of person who possesses it.
